# Can I Send And Receive Push Notifications On My Website With Urban Airship?

Tags: javascript, urbanairship.com

This is the scenario for my website:

1.) I am a `Student` who is waiting for a `Question`

2.) A `Professor` sends a `Question` to his `Students` for them to answer

3.) The `Student`'s website page will change to the `QuestionPage` where the `Student` can answer the `Question`


Basically I'm wondering if I can use Urban Airship to push and pull these push notifications on my website.  Urban Airship does have Javascript documentation, but it looks like it's only compatible for PhoneGap/Cordova (there seems to be some config files and such that I don't have on my website).  Furthermore, there are some `npm` node modules for Urban Airship to work on my website, but it looks like they only allow pushing the notification rather than receiving them.  i.e. you can push notifications OUT to other devices, but you can't push the notifications to another user using the website.

My knowledge here is limited since I've never done any real-time web stuff, so thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urban Airship is not a browser push provider; it supports push to mobile (e.g. iOS, Android) devices only. However, Urban Airship supports integrations with a browser push provider, [Roost](https://goroost.com/blog/roost-urban-airship-connect), which may help you accomplish your goal if you need to send notifications to both mobile native applications (which includes natively deployable webapps such as those build with Cordova/Phonegap) as well as browsers.